# Memory allocation for strings and arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, debugging, memory

First function:

1. concatenate string and integer into one string.
2. insert result string into an array.
3. join all array's strings into one string.

Second function does the same, but instead of concatenation, it inserts 2 strings in the array.

**Question:** How do you figure out what function will allocate less memory?
**One more question:** How many strings in  memory (for each iteration) for first function we will have? For example, for 1st iteration we will have only "a0" or "a0", "a" and "0"?

```
function joinLetters() {
    var arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        arr.push('a' + i);
    }
    return arr.join('');
}

function joinLetters2() {
    var arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        arr.push('a');
        arr.push(i.toString());
    }
    return arr.join('');
}
```

Comment: Functions don't allocate memory... executing them does, often in ways that vary depending upon the execution environment. As StackOverflow is forever, so should this question, yet we can't predict the future, whether it'll still be valid to deduce the first function uses less memory for example.

Comment: would you please accept/vote up my answer if you found it useful?

Answer (score 0):

`joinLetters` in the inner loop makes a single push, `joinLetters2` does two `push` instead.

So you will have in the first case `arr.length = 10000`, while in the second  `arr.length = 20000`.

Definitely you can expect the second function to be more memory expensive then the first.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: How many strings in  memory (for each iteration) for first function we will have? For example, for 1st iteration we will have only "a0" or "a0", "a" and "0"?

Comment: Obviously if you do a single push you will have a single element, not `a,0,...`. For such questions pls see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)